# how i can replace text of bookmark when bookmark is in the table?

Tags: openxml-sdk

I use this code to replace text of bookmark in word :

```
using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open("doc3.docx", true))
{

    var bookmarkStarts = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<BookmarkStart>();

    foreach (var start in bookmarkStarts)
    {
       OpenXmlElement elem = item.NextSibling();

                while (elem != null && !(elem is BookmarkEnd))
                {
                    OpenXmlElement nextElem = elem.NextSibling();
                    elem.Remove();
                    elem = nextElem;
                }

                item.Parent.InsertBefore<Run>(new Run(new Text("Hello")), item);
    }  
    wordDoc.Close();
}
```

But this not work where the bookmark is in the table.

Comment: Have you tried `wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save()` before the `wordDoc.Close()` command?

Comment: yes i try it but when bookmark is in the table , word created with this error : the office open xml file ...**.**doc cannot be opened because there are problems with the contents

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that you don't delete any bookmarks with your approach?
I've run your test code after editing a little (you don't have a var name items in your example code), and I've succesfully inserted Hello in 2 bookmarks out of a table, and 2 in a table, without any issues.

Which leads me to believe your problem lies elsewhere.
Have you looked at the open-xml in your document after you've run your program?
Is there any errors?

I've experienced bookmarks being placed the oddest places in a word-document when you leave the placing to word, and not you.

You can also end up with bookmarks overlapping each other like this

```
<bookmark1 start><xml xml><bookmark2 start><bookmark1 end><xml xml><bookmark2 end>
```

If you run into that case, your code will delete the bookmarkstart 2 before it reaches bookmarkend 1, and that will cause your bookmark to not be replaced.

You'll easily run into that problem with larger complex documents.
The way I solved it was to "sort" the bookmarks before doing any editing.

So the example above would become

```
<bookmark1 start><xml xml><bookmark1 end><bookmark2 start><xml xml><bookmark2 end>
```

after the sort

The code I use to do this look like this:

```
var bookmarks = mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<BookmarkStart>(); 
for (int i = 0; i < bookmarks.Count(); i++)
{
    var bks = bookmarks.ElementAt(i);
    var next = bks.NextSibling();
    if (next is BookmarkEnd)
    {
        var bme = (BookmarkEnd)next;
        if (int.Parse(bks.Id) - int.Parse(bme.Id) == 1)
        {
            var copy = (BookmarkEnd)next.Clone();
            bks.Parent.RemoveChild<BookmarkEnd>(bme);
            bks.Parent.InsertBefore<BookmarkEnd>(copy, bks);
        }
    }
}
```

Which i'll admit isn't totally fool-proof but have worked well for me.
Another check you can add, to avoid deleting bookmarks is in your replace method

This will make sure you don't delete bookmarkstarts as you remove elements when inserting text

```
while (elem != null && !(elem is BookmarkEnd)) //fjern elementer
            {
                OpenXmlElement nextElem = elem.NextSibling();
                if (elem.LocalName != "bookmarkStart")
                    elem.Remove();
                elem = nextElem;
            }
```

Good luck :)